# PXE Boot iSCSI wait time

Tags: pxe, iscsi

I am deploying a single Laptop via PXE boot over a wired network.

It runs perfectly, DHCP connects, TFTP finds and loads config data, scsi sends over the boot partition.  Then it pauses for a minute

Looking at the dmesg logs, there is a 62 second gap before the scsi initiator starts to try to load the root partition.  This happens every time.  The other scsi-ahci connections have started up fine, but the iscsi initiator just hangs.  Looking at tcpdump, there is no communication during this period.

What is going on here?  Can I remove this waiting period?

The host server is running RHEL Server 7, and it the only other thing on the network besides the laptop (literally a single copper cable).